# ehCache is evicting the entries even though eternal is set to true

Tags: ehcache-2

. The cache objects values are hibernate entities bear in mind it had stored in level 2 cache as well. When we see the Ehcache statistics , it is always twice the no of objects . We thought we set eternal to true to our cache , but it seems keys present but value is disappeared , we suspect the entities are evicted from hibernate l2 cache . It’s really so difficult to re produce

Comment: We want the cache to never expire .  But the values are hibernate entities .  It seems we get random evictions ,

Answer (score 0):

The problem is identified .

Our app is using hibernate query level cache and second level cache also.  On the startup , we have a configuration ( which is cached in query level and second level) cached into our own cache ( using hCache).  When hibernate executes a native query which is a commit  for one of the entity  ,  hibernate is invalidating the second level cache for most of the entities .